# Php function return empty json to Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I use ajax to check if it's the first time that the user logs in:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/checkFirstLogin.php',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {'user_id': userId},
  success: function(data) {
          if(data == 'firstTime') {

                 showWelcome();//this open a popup
           }else{

                alert('been here before');
           }
        },//end success
}); // end ajax call
```

`checkFirstLogin.php` simply does this:

```
<?php require 'core/init.php';


        $user_id = filter_var($_POST['user_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
            $myUser = new User($user_id);


                    $myUser->checkFirstLogin();

                            if($myUser){

                                $response = 'firstTime';

                                    echo json_encode($response);


                                        }else{

                                            $response = 'beenHere';


                            echo json_encode($response);

                                        }
```

User::checkFirstLogin():

```
   public function checkFirstLogin(){

   $sth = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE first_login = '0' AND user_id= ? ");
   $sth->bindParam(1, $this->data()->user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $sth->execute();
   $data_exists = ($sth->fetchColumn() > 0) ? true : false;

     return $data_exists;
}
```

json response is always "firstTime" even when first_time = 1 in the database.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're checking `$myUser`, not the actual return value of the function; what you mean to do is probably something like;

```
$is_new_user = $myUser->checkFirstLogin();

if($is_new_user) {
    $response = 'firstTime';

...
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!! I think I spent too many hours on this computer. that's what I meant to do! you have been too quick to notice that. now I have to wait 3 more minutes to accept your answer. ;) cheers